# JMeter + Selenium testing stops after Firefox is opened

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium, webdriver, jmeter

I tried to learn JMeter+Selenium but there is small problem:
I started with this:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler
done everything to the heading "Code Review".
When I run Thread group it opens Firefox but does not open requested website.

My FF version is 34.0.5

JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.2.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](http://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide

**Q. How do I Know Which Browsers are Supported?** section explains how to identify appropriate Firefox version for WebDriver plugin.

- JMeterPlugins-WebDriver-1.2.0 contains **selenium-firefox-driver-2.39.0.jar**
- Looking into [Selenium changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG)

  ```
  v2.39.0
  =======
  WebDriver:
  * Update to support native events for Firefox 26.
  ```

So you need to use **Firefox 26** with WebDriver-1.2.0 plugin version. You can download Firefox 26 from [Mozilla FTP site](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/26.0/)

Comment: It worked perfectly. Downloaded firefox 26 from here: https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-26.0&os=linux&lang=en-US

Ubuntu:
1. uninstall firefox: sudo apt-get purge firefox
2. download firefox 26
3. unpack: sudo tar xjf firefox-xxx.tar.bz2
4. ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing any native calls in the driver, such as .get  or  .sendKeys, then the latest version of Firefox you can use is 31.0.6 .  If you avoid those native calls and do non-native Javascript calls instead, such as using a JavascriptExecutor to navigate the browser, then you should be able to use a later version of Firefox.